# mysql Calculate sum IF by Group

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, sum

mysql5.7
I have table below and I'm attempting to create calculated table of qty*price and distributor commissions (if total qty>100, 4% commissions, else 2%) grouped by product_name

```
Id   product_name        quantity price
1    Alpha               100      6000
2    Bravo               80       5500
3    Alpha               70       6000
4    Charlie             41       5500
5    Delta               12       3000
6    Echo                20       3100
7    Echo                30       3200
8    Delta               90       3300
9    Bravo               100      5500
```

```
SELECT product_name,
    SUM(quantity*price) as 'Value (qty x price)',
    IF(SUM(quantity)>100,".04",".02")*(quantity*price) as 'Distributor Commission'
FROM transaction_details
GROUP BY product_name;
```

From the code below I have successfully calculated the 'Value (qty x price)'
HOWEVER for 'Distributor Commission' my code seems to take the first line found in the table of product_name, instead of the actual TOTAL or sum(quantity)

How can I write it so that it calculates the total by the group?

Comment: Two answers, one assuming "total qty" meant total for that product, and the other I think total over all products, though the second answer was incomplete

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want:

```
SELECT product_name,
    SUM(quantity*price) as `Value (qty x price)`,
    CASE WHEN SUM(quantity) > 100 THEN 0.04 ELSE 0.02 END 
        * SUM(quantity * price) as `Distributor Commission`
FROM transaction_details
GROUP BY product_name;
```

Rationale:

- you want to compute the commission over on the total sales value (so you need a `SUM()` on the right side of the multiplication)
- identifiers (such as column aliases for example) should be surrounded with backticks rather than single quotes
- I rewrote the `IF` condition as a `CASE` expression instead (although both are valid in MySQL, I like `CASE` better, because it is standard SQL)

Comment: That is correct, thank YOu. But, how is this different with the use of IF?

Comment: Maybe explain?  You made two changes, one of which was just stylistic, which may confuse

Comment: @ysth: yes I was typing... I just did.

Comment: @GMB appreciate the clarity!!

Comment: @ysth . . . `case` is not *stylistic*.  It is **standard** SQL.  `if` is a bespoke extension in MySQL.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'm finding answer for this question.

Answer (score 0):

from the discussion of the comments it seems you want below

```
    SELECT product_name,
    SUM(quantity*price) as 'Value (qty x price)',
    sum(IF( 
     (select SUM(quantity) 
       )>100,.04,.02)*  (quantity*price)) as 'Distributor Commission'
FROM transaction_details a
GROUP BY product_name;
```